# Laravel : What is the difference between `locale` and `fallback_locale`?

Tags: laravel

There are two items in `\config\app.php`:

```
 'locale' => 'en',

 'fallback_locale' => 'en',
```

What is the difference between them?

Comment: If the `locale` is not available for some reasons (mispelling, bugs ...), then the `fallback_locale` will be chosen.

Answer (score 4):

From the docs :

> You may configure a "fallback language", which will be used when the active language does not contain a given translation string. Like the default language, the fallback language is also configured in the config/app.php configuration file.

Have a look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/localization)